# Can someone point me to a good example of using bayesian models for making marketing decisions?

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo

I am tasked to build a bayesian model to support decision making for paid search marketing. I've researched online and found several scholarly articles on using Hierarchical Bayesian model or MCMC in estimating model parameters, but I still don't understand details. Is there a good example somewhere, which explains both the model, and how to use a software package to estimate the parameters step by step? Thank you!

Comment: Are you familiar with Bayesian inference at all? What about programming? The reason I ask is to understand your background.

Comment: Hi! Yes, I understand basic Bayesian inference, and I can program in java. Any advice would be great. Thank you!

Comment: well, there do appear to be some MCMC java libraries (which is needed for Bayesian inference), HYDRA seems to be popular. Alternatively, there is JAGS, BUGS which are popular non-Java options. This assumes knowledge of how to use MCMC in Bayesian inference though. Personally, I had difficult time going from Bayesian theory to Bayesian practice, but after understanding (and taking more time than I care to mention), I wrote an [ebook](https://github.com/CamDavidsonPilon/Probabilistic-Programming-and-Bayesian-Methods-for-Hackers) to help others. It uses Python and PyMC. Might this help?